# xfce4-power-manager does not Off Fan in Debian 8

Tags: laptop, debian, power-management, fan, xfce4

I have recently installed Debian 8 for amd64 on my laptop. The laptop is dell vostro. I also installed LXDE environment. To manage power I installed xfce4-power-manager (because it was recommend for lxde). Now I have a problem with the fan. After I closed the lid, the fan is still working. In xfce4-power-manager-settings I have of course set the behavior when lid is close on HIBERNATE. I want to add that when I used Debian 7.8 I have this same configuration and I did not have any problem with the fan. What I can check, set?

Comment: What happens if you execute `systemctl hibernate`?

Comment: This same effect. Display OFF, hdd OFF, FAN still ON.